# Как отправить электронное письмо?

Tags: python

Всем доброго дня.Как отправить электронное письмо с помощью Python?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Как так? Я не понимаю

Comment: Коротко - с помощью библиотеки smtplib (протокол SMTP).

Comment: код не работает

Comment: Так добавьте тот, что не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Работает для gmail почты.

```
            sender = 'youradress@gmail.com'
            subject = 'Напишите свою тему сообщения'
            message = 'твоя почта работает или нет?'
            text = '<html><head></head><body><p>' + message + '</p></body></html>'
            msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            msg['Subject'] = subject
            msg['From'] = 'Business Team <' + sender + '>'
            msg['To'] = recipient
            msg['Reply-To'] = sender
            msg['Return-Path'] = sender
            msg['X-Mailer'] = 'Python/' + (python_version())
            html1 = MIMEText(text, 'html')
            msg.attach(html1)
            mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            mailServer.ehlo()
            mailServer.starttls()
            mailServer.ehlo()
            mailServer.login(user, password)
            mailServer.sendmail(user, recipient, msg.as_string())
            mailServer.close()
            print('письмo отправленο ... ')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `msg['date'] = formatdate(timeval=time(), localtime=True)` добавьте, а то дата в сообщении в принимающем клиенте будет проставляться по факту получения клиентом